# Как правильно сделать отображение пагинации в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

Как правильно сделать отображение пагинации, пример: `Показ 1–5 из 11 Результата`. Когда нажать на страницу пагинатора к примеру 2 чтобы показало `Показ 6-10 из 11 Результата`, а если последний то `11 из 11` в контроллере получаю так:

```
public function products()
{ 
    $products = Product::where('availability', '1')->orderBy('order', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    $quantity = Product::where('availability', '1')->get()->count();

    return view('products', compact('products', 'quantity'));

}
```

```html
<span>Показ 1–{{$products->count()}} из {{$quantity}} Результата</span>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую обратить внимание на документацию - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

- В blade шаблоне шаблоне:

  Показ {{ ($products->currentPage() -1 ) * $products->perPage() + 1 }} - 
  {{ $products->currentPage() * $products->perPage() - ( $products->perPage() - $products->count() ) }} из {{ $quantity }}

Выведет Вам:

- Показ 1-5 из 11
- Показ 6-10 из 11
- Показ 11-11 из 11

Нужно будет еще допилить напильником, но, надеюсь, идея ясна?